# IF-ELIF statements nested

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I was wondering if there was a better way of writing this. The current code stated below works. i was just wondering if there was a better way.

This is for validation. So the if statements check all the mandatory fields and if they are acceptable, then it goes onto the execution code. The issue started because the entry field for

> `self.text_fmax`

was not being accepted as integer. So this specific field, first it is checked if empty then ignored, if not then the value has to be an integer between 0 and 180.

```
  def call_back(self):
    if len(self.text_n.get()) == 0:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Mandatory Information", "Please input an integer value for Number of Tessellations Cells")
    elif len(self.text_id.get()) == 0:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Mandatory Information", "Please input an integer value for Tessellation Identifier")
    elif len(domain_container) == 0:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Mandatory Information", "Please input Domain")
    elif len(self.text_fmax.get()) != 0:
        a = int(self.text_fmax.get())
        if a < 0 or a > 180:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Incorrect Value", "Face Flatness should be less than 180")
        elif len(filename4) == 0:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Mandatory Information", "Please input Output File Name")
        else:
            self.execute_neper_code()
    elif len(filename4) == 0:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Mandatory Information", "Please input Output File Name")
    else:
        self.execute_neper_code()
```

Comment: If this code is working, it seems like the question is more appropriate to [the Code Review StackExchange site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: thanks for that, i never knew taht such a site existed. Am still a newbie at Pyton2.7. I will post there as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually don't need to check `len == 0`, just test the objects "truthiness".

```
def call_back(self):
    show = tkMessageBox.showinfo
    if not self.text_n.get():
        show("Mandatory Information", "Please input an integer value for Number of Tessellations Cells")

    elif not self.text_id.get():
        show("Mandatory Information", "Please input an integer value for Tessellation Identifier")

    elif not domain_container:
        show("Mandatory Information", "Please input Domain")

    elif self.text_fmax.get() and not 0 <= int(self.text_fmax.get()) <= 180:
        show("Incorrect Value", "Face Flatness should be less than 180")

    elif not filename4:
        show("Mandatory Information", "Please input Output File Name")

    else:
        self.execute_neper_code()
```

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the code... However, what i am actually looking for is to eliminate having to validate "filename4" twice once inside the inner loop and once outside in the outer loop.

Comment: @AlyAbdelaziz, ok looking at that now

Comment: Note: if i do not do the "len" check, the program does not ignore if the entry field is left empty and gives and error. So first i check if empty, if NOT, then i check the integer value.

Comment: Right, but you don't need to use `if len(somestr) != 0...`, you can use `if somestr...`

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work. I understand where you are going with the "if" statement only. I think i just found the "len" method easier, i guess. Thanks for the updated code.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below method if you want to avoid repetitive code and strings.
Below is not complete code but simple example. Key in `t_msgs` dict represents the field to be validated and value(can be range) to be validated against.

```
def call_back(self):
    t_msgs = {"mdt": "Mandatory Information",
              "incrt_val" :"Incorrect Value"}
    checkFields = {(self.text_n, 0): 
                    (t_msgs["mdt"], 
                     "Please input an integer value for Number of Tessellations Cells"),
                   (self.text_id, 0): 
                    (t_msgs["mdt"], 
                     "Please input an integer value for Tessellation Identifier"),
                   (domain_container, 0): 
                    (t_msgs["mdt"], 
                     "Please input Domain"),
                   (self.text_fmax, range(0, 181, 180)): 
                    (t_msgs["incrt_val"], 
                     "Face Flatness should be less than 180"),
                   (len(filename4), 0): 
                    (t_msgs["mdt"], 
                     "Please input Output File Name")}

    for field in checkFields:
        if not field[1]:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo(checkFields[field][0], checkFields[field][1])
        else:
            if not (field[1][0] < field[0].get() < field[1][1]):
                tkMessageBox.showinfo(checkFields[field[0]], checkFields[field][1])
```